# Run Asp .Net projects on mac and windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, macos, visual-studio

Microsoft released the first preview version of Visual Studio for Mac a few days a ago. Which is really cool.
I am using a Mac during school and a Windows machine at home. 
My Asp .Net projects are saved on a USB drive. When i am at school i want to edit my stuff on my Mac and when I come home I just want to insert the USB drive on my PC and keep on working.

Is there a easy way for me to do that?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the projects on these computers and modify them?

Comment: Only ASP.NET Core projects are supposed to be supported right now. Sonic you are doing ASP.NET 4 you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do that, you can create .net core project and it should works fine, or you can use mono project, but i don't recommend it.